# How to unassign stock programatically?

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

I'm using MSI for inventory management.

I've imports products and by default Magento assigned **default stock** to every products.

So I need to reassign products to my custom created stock that is under `Stores->Configurations->stocks`

I've created new stock from above and assigned my sources to it.

Than after I've imported sources using default import/export functions.

After than product updated as per data provided.

But issue I'm facing is after I import sources then previously assigned stock and sources information is still there and displays at product grid as well as in product form.

Can anybody have solution to this ? In short I want to remove old stock which is currently out-of-stock ?

Any hack/workaround will also work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use my below script to remove Stock sources from all products.
It loops through all products, and removes the stock source you enter in the foreach loop.

> file: pub/RemoveStock.php

```
<?php

if(php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
echo 'You shall not pass!';
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$sourceItemInterfaceFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory');
$sourceItemsDeleteInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsDeleteInterface');



$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
$sourceItem = $sourceItemInterfaceFactory->create();

$sourceItem->setSourceCode('<set stock id here!>');
$sourceItem->setSku($product->getSku());

$sourceItemsDeleteInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
}
```

You can run the script by with this command: `php RemoveStock.php`

Hope this helps.